# как узнать что убило процесс?

Tags: bash

запустил по ssh bash скрипт с коротким содержанием: php test.php.
Процесс повисел повисел и вдруг на консоль вывелось killed.
Запустил снова, на соседней вкладке открыл htop. Оперативной памяти потреблялось не больше 70%, процесс завершился удачно. Что могло убить процесс или вывести подобное сообщение?
Думал может соединение поравилось с сервером, но все ок. Пытался самостоятельно сейчам прибать браузер через killall, Но ничего подобного в консоли не увидел, процесс просто завершался.

Comment: Скорее всего, нехватка оперативки, из-за которой OOM killer прибил какой-то толстый процесс, из-за чего оперативки стало хватать и потому повторный запуск завершился успехом. Мы же о Linux говорим сейчас? Вы б добавили соответствующую метку.

Comment: ```Но ничего подобного в консоли не увидел``` - чтобы что-то годное увидеть в консоли, надо уметь пользоваться консолью, а точнее, командами

Comment: видно что-нибудь  интересное в /var/log/messages ?

Comment: Ядро убило. Как написана программа, так и работает.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй запустить с strace и вывод складывая в файл, типо так:

```
strace -f php test.php &> log.txt
```

Если упадет пробуй понять из лога в какой момент и почему.